# How to set enum values to dropdown in ASP.MVC 5, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the enum value that I need to set in the dropdown, but I am not able to do so.

```
 public static List<SelectListItem> GetDraft(int selectedGroupId)
{
    List<SelectListItem> data = new List<SelectListItem>();
    // attempt 1 
    data.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = Hello.SIM, Text = "Create New Draft" });
                                               ^^ I want the value to be "2", compile time error as Value can only be string

    // attempt 2 
    data.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = Hello.SIM.ToString(), Text = "Create New Draft" });
                                               ^^ I want the value to be "2" but now it comes out to be string as "SIM"
    // below are some other values that I need to set and they are working as expected as they are not ENUM
    // some code has been removed for brevity
    foreach (dsSimSettings.DraftRow row in draftData.Rows)
    {
        data.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = row.idDraft.ToString(), Text = row.strDescription });
    }
    return data;
}

public enum Hello
{
   SIM = 2
}
```

**EDIT**

```
[AuthorizeSettings]
        public JsonResult GetDrafts(int groupId)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> drafts = SecurityHelper.GetDraft(groupId);
            return Json(drafts);
        }
```

Comment: How/where do you use the `GetDraft` method ?

Comment: @Béranger: Added the edit

Comment: I just need one enum, that's it. Rest all dropdowns are fine. Just the first one needs to be ENUM and I want the value as "2".

Comment: Have you tried Hello.SIM.ToString()

Comment: @FailedUnitTest: Check my attempt 2, provided in the code snippet. it gives value as "SIM" and not "2"

Comment: You can take a look at my answer

Comment: Having the `Value` of "SIM"` is fine - its just hat you need to bind to your `enum`, not `int` e.g. `GetDrafts(Hello groupId)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I have learned so much from your answers in stack over. thanks for that first. Coming back to my question the problem is rest of the dropdown values are normal values coming from DB. I mean rest all  are values like "2", "3" etc. But just the first one was suppose to be the enum.

Comment: That seems a rather odd design - when you post back, how would you know if the selected value is supposed to be the `enum` or just an `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the enum value using :

```
((int)Hello.SIM).ToString()
```